# How to override the window.open functionality?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have window.open (without name parameter), scattered in my project and I want to change the implementation so that wherever name is not specified I'll specify a default name.

What I want to do about this is hook my own method to window.open so that whenever window.open runs it'll internally call my own method which will then call window.open (with the name parameter).

Is that possible through Javascript? Will there be any circular dependency issues in this i.e. window.open calling my custom function which in turn calling the window.open function again?

P.s. In simple terms what I want to do is override the window.open functionality.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To avoid circular calls, you need to stash away the original `window.open` function in a variable.

A nice way (that doesn't pollute the global namespace) is to use a closure. Pass the original `window.open` function to an anonymous function as an argument (called `open` below). This anonymous function is a factory for your hook function. Your hook function is permanently bound to the original `window.open` function via the `open` argument:

```
window.open = function (open) {
    return function (url, name, features) {
        // set name if missing here
        name = name || "default_window_name";
        return open.call(window, url, name, features);
    };
}(window.open);
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here? I'm not well versed with JS I'm afraid.

Comment: I explained it with an update above. I don't think I can go into deeper details than this. I recommend reading up on: 1. Function scopes and the call/apply methods. 2. Module patterns.

Comment: It's giving this JS error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'call'

Comment: IE never fails to fail. Can you try directly calling open? `return open(window, url, name, features);`

Comment: :) It gave me this: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid argument. after I removed the call word. I changed "return open(window, url, name, features);" to "return open(url, name);" and it worked. Now the question is whether this is browser agnostic or not...

Comment: Sorry, yes, you need to remove the `window` argument when you're not using `call`, obviously. It may not be cross-browser! You might have to do a check to see if the `open` object has a `call` method and act accordingly: `return open.call ? open.call(window, ...) : open(...);` The unavoidable yuckiness of intrinsic browser objects...

Comment: @Ates Goral This opens a popup but with the argument appended to the current URL.
e.g: if I say window.open('www.google.com') it opens a new window directed to http://mycurrenturl.com/www.google.com .. am seeing this in both IE and chrome
here's an example:http://jsfiddle.net/XeEEx/

Comment: @SajjanSarkar Try prepending the URL with a "http://". Without it, the browser has no way of telling that your intention is to go to another domain instead of a relative path.

Comment: @Ates Goral Perfect, you are the man! cant believe I didnt see that..Time for a coffee..

Answer (score 15):

I know this reply is a little late, but I felt that a more general solution may be helpful for other people (trying to override other methods)

```
function wrap(object, method, wrapper){
    var fn = object[method];

    return object[method] = function(){
        return wrapper.apply(this, [fn.bind(this)].concat(
            Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};

//You may want to 'unwrap' the method later 
//(setting the method back to the original)
function unwrap(object, method, orginalFn){
    object[method] = orginalFn;
};

//Any globally scoped function is considered a 'method' of the window object 
//(If you are in the browser)
wrap(window, "open", function(orginalFn){
    var originalParams = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    console.log('open is being overridden');
    //Perform some logic
    //Call the original window.open with the original params
    orginalFn.apply(undefined, originalParams); 
});
```

Comment: Nice clean generic way of hooking an object's function

Answer (score 10):

> P.s. In simple terms what I want to do is override the window.open
>   functionality.

```
var orgOpen = window.open;

window.open = function (...args) {
    alert("Overrided!"); 
    return orgOpen(...args); 
}

window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: 1. Pollutes global namespace. 2. Hook function does not use any arguments. 3. Hook function does not return the new window object. 4. How did this even work?

Comment: I wouldn't care that much about namespace pollution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by storing a reference to the original **window.open** function and then overriding it with your own implementation. Here's an example:

```js
const originalWindowOpen = window.open;

// Override window.open
window.open = function(url, target = 'defaultName', windowFeatures) {
    console.log('New window or tab opened!', url, target, windowFeatures);
    return originalWindowOpen.call(window, url, target, windowFeatures);
};
```

In the above code, we first store the original **window.open** in a constant. Then, we override the window.open function with our own logic. Inside our custom window.open, we can add any additional logic we need (like logging) and then call the original function with the call method, preventing any circular dependency issues.