# Intercept new URL before unloading page

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem**: I'm a user that needs to use a Web app that has a list of anchors with `href="javascript://"`. When I click any of them, a script executes some stuff (irrelevant here) and finally navigates to a new page.

My problem is that I want this new page to be loaded on a new tab, instead of having my current tab navigating to a different page. Since the link points to nowhere, I can't right-click it and open it in a new tab.

(the reason I want this is because I must always go back and forth, so if each item could be loaded in a different tab it'd save me a huge amount of time)

**Question**: *Is it possible to intercept the new URL to be loaded before the window unloads?* Or is this impossible without a browser extension, even if using the console to execute the script?

**Ideas for solution**: If `window.onbeforeunload` could capture the new URL, to be assigned to `window.location`, I could `window.open(newURL,'_blank')` and then prevent default behaviour of navigating to new URL.

---

- **UPDATE** : changing `window.open`, `window.history.pushSate` or `replaceState`, `window.location.assign` or `replace`, to `null` makes no difference, so none of those is being called. It's most likely using `window.location`. Is it possible to listen to any calls to `window.location`? Or can I add something to `location` so that `location = newURL` or `location.href = newURL` do not redirect, but instead just opens a new tab with this `newURL`?
- **2nd UPDATE** : I solved my problem by inverting the expected behaviour. Instead of being able to open each item in a new tab, I make each click on an item open in a new tab the previous URL before navigating to the new page. That is, I added an `eventListener` to each item and when it gets clicked it runs this: `myNewTab = window.open(originalURL, '_blank'); myScript = document.createElement('script'), myScript.innerHTML = "/*eventual custom script goes here*/"; myNewTab.document.body.appendChild(myScript);`. I'd still like to know though if it's possible to intercept the new  URL, because this would still be the best solution

Comment: Can you just edit the JS code and make it open in new window? I would also suggest click events over `javascript://`.

Comment: @JBis that's the tricky part. The new URL is a result of multiple functions being called, it's really hard to find out what is the URL, and in this maze of functions one of it makes the page navigate to the new URL, but I can't find which it is. The Web app is poorly coded, but I'm not its developer and I must use it

Comment: Look for `window.open`

Comment: @JBis good idea, I found 15 instances, with variables such as "er" and other senseless names. But is `window.open` the only way to navigate to a new URL? Can't `window.location.replace` , `window.location.assign` or something else that I'm missing also do this? The problem of checking each of the 15 instances is that they're the result of other functions, so it'll take quite a while to read the whole thing

Comment: Is new url added to history? Look at the functions on MDN and see where they are used and the symptoms when they are used. Then diagnose the function used.

Comment: @JBis, you're right, it's added to history, so can't be `window.location.replace`. But do you know whether it's possible to intercept the new URL? Or the call to `window.open`? This would be much quicker then delving into the whole code, which will take me hours possibly

Comment: Not that I know of. That would be very insecure if site could see where your leaving to.

Comment: Wait. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172505/how-to-override-the-window-open-functionality

Comment: Create your own function. That opens it in new tab

Comment: @JBis Wow, that's genious! Thanks! But, alas!, `window.open` is not called. I substituted it with the same thing plus an `alert('this was called');`, and no alert was given

Comment: Some common ways to update the browser history are the `window.history.pushState`, `window.history.replaceState` methods. Or browser could be sending something to the server to make the final decision, like a normal httpRequest or possibly something like `window.location.search`.  (The `window` object may or may not be explicitly named in any case, browsers assume that's the object you want if you use an unqualified method or property name.) You could also check for an `href` being set somewhere, although this seems less likely. That might give you a few more leads at least.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Cat ! It's a HttpRequest that's being sent when I click. I changed `window.location.assign` and `replace` to null, but they're not being called. The query is being updated, but so is a part of the url. It goes from `...dropbox/admin/mark/folder_submissions_users.d2l?...` to `.../mark/folder_user_mark.d2l?...`. I think it's changing `location` directly, but there are more than 70 matches in the code for `location=` or `location.href= `. I'll have to pour though them. Is there anyway to change how `location=` works?

Comment: If you just want a workaround, you could ask your browser to duplicate the current tab, either programmatically (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/duplicate) or manually (alt+D>Enter works in Chrome and possibly Firefox: https://lifehacker.com/duplicate-a-google-chrome-tab-with-a-shortcut-key-5387881)

Comment: @Cat I'm already doing this:) The problem is that for each item I need to click, I also need to open a tab (because I first need to open the page with the list of anchors and then click on the anchor I want) and then I get confused with so many tabs (which are the important ones?). If nothing can be done, then it's just the way life is, but it'd be super useful to intercept the new URL and open it in a new tab

Answer (score 1):

Since you've isolated the problem (apparently) to instances of `location=` and `location.href=`, you should be able to hack all of these from the global namespace.
You could start by defining

```
var location = {};
```

All the offending assignment statements should now be rendered harmless.

If this means other parts of your inherited code fail, or if you just want a more thorough solution, you can wrap the entire client-side codebase (except your custom `location` object) in a function that reacts whenever your that object changes. A useful response would be to create an `a` tag with `target="_blank"` and `href=" ${location.href} || ${location} || #`, or something similar.

---

Alternatively, you could make your custom location object immutable (untested):

```
const location = {};
Object.defineProperty( location, "href", {
  value: "whatever",
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```

Now any attempts to assign to `location` or `location.href` will throw an error such as `[Invalid_const_assignment][1]`. If your wrapping function uses a try/catch to execute the rest of the sourcecode, you can catch these errors to keep the app running anyway, see what url the assignment was attempting to send you to, and hopefully do something useful with it.

---

Finally, if the original develper used `window.location` explicitly instead of `location`, that's a bigger fish, but you have a couple of options.

One is to find and replace all instances of the former with the latter to make the above suggestions applicable. One way to accomplish this would be with the "find in folder" menu option in Sublime Text (after opening your src folder with Sublime.) Obviously, you'd need to make a reliable backup (such as a git commit) before making such reckless global changes.

Another is to try to hack the window object. This starts to go beyond reckless and should probably be prevented by any respectable browser, but maybe a wrapping function (as described above) that the browser doesn't know about can simulate this.

That is, if the execution context for your app's sourcecode is a wrapping function with its own "local" `window`  object, then any interactions with `window.someProperty` or `window.someMethod` should find your custom version, which could act as a gatekeeper to add custom handling for some properties (like `location`) while forwarding all other assignments and method calls on to the "real" window object.

This forwarding is probably the hard part, depending on what specific interactions the app is trying to have with `window`. If there are few interactions to worry about, you could preemptively handle each type on a case-by-case basis, but we're already outside the scope of my knowledge, and a dynamic solution for this case (maybe using a proxy object?) is something I'm not even going to speculate on further.

Instead, here are [someone else's (related?) thoughts](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1838-wrapping-the-window-object-in-a-jquery-wrapper.htm) working with jQuery, but if you've got to go this far, writing a small browser extension to handle automatically duplicating and removing the additional tabs as needed may be a simpler workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attempts to solve it! Sorry, but unless I'm missing something, I don't think `location` is configurable in this manner (it's not possible to assign it something else, such as `location = {}`). I read the blogpost you referenced, but I couldn't make it work, at least via console (did browsers change these rules now?). I'm just a user and I'm changing the page through the browser's console, I can't change anything back-end. I also thought I could perhaps write a wrapper for `window` or `location`, but it's not working

Comment: Maybe a browser extension would work, but then it's too much trouble for me, I'd also have to learn how to make an extension. Maybe I'll have to be content with the workaround you suggested, of using ALT+D & ALT+ENTER everytime (this has other problems too, I have first to click to sort the list, but nevermind)

Comment: Oh, lame. Sorry I should have checked about `location` being assignable-to before suggesting it. Not having access to the server makes it much tougher. If you decide to go the extension route, it's probably  not as complicated as you think if you already know some javascript (See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted). If you don't have access to the server or an extension, how are you planning to execute your code to capture the url? Just in the console?? Or a tampermonkey script or something, maybe?

Comment: I was being optimistic and I thought the console would do... tampermonkey is the closest I guess without an extension. I'm actually running additional code in the console, just because the Web app is so bad it can't even sort the list, I have to realign everything. Thanks for the link though!