# prevent overriding of JavaScript function/method to open a page

Tags: javascript, overriding

The following code (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172505/how-to-override-the-window-open-functionality) on StackOverflow):

```
var orgOpen = window.open;

window.open = function (url, windowName, windowFeatures) {
    alert("Overrided!"); 
    return orgOpen(url, windowName, windowFeatures); 
}

window.open('https://www.google.com')
```

overrides the window.open method. I didn't know that it was possible.

I'm trying to write a bookmarklet to run on some pages and I want to be sure that such pages cannot know the url of the page I'm opening and cannot hijack my code.

Is it possible, that is, is there any function/method to open a new page that cannot be overrided?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible. You're running your code in their sandbox, you play by their rules.

Comment: Does it have to be a bookmarklet? You might get more security with a browser extension.

Comment: @Barman I'm not able to write an addon. Anyway, I think it will be more difficult to write an addon. Moreover, I don't know if Mozilla (I use firefox) will validate it.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck.

Comment: `const mine = window.open` but you won't know if that was already changed before.